# Probability Determinant of Poisson Process Maze is Nonzero

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, stochastic-processes

**Source**: There was a IMO shortlist problem (don't have the link) about sequences of numbers along the diagonals of these patterns and I was interested in creating an unrelated extension.

> Suppose a monkey is making a spiral maze of numbers by moving in a counter-clockwise-like fashion:
> $$
> \begin{bmatrix}
>     1
> \end{bmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
>     1 & 2
> \end{bmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
>    \cdot & 3 \\ 1 & 2
> \end{bmatrix}$$
> $$\rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
>     4 & 3 \\ 1 & 2
> \end{bmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
>     5 & 4 & 3 \\ \cdot & 1 & 2 
> \end{bmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
>     5 & 4 & 3 \\ 6 & 1 & 2
> \end{bmatrix}\rightarrow\cdots
> $$
> But suppose the monkey is quite lazy and likes to take breaks when placing the numbers. In particular, assume that the distribution of the monkey's break, $T_i$, between placing the $(i-1)$*th* and $i$*th* number is given by
> $$P(T_i>t)=e^{-\lambda t}$$
> and that each break time, $i\in\mathbb{N}$, is independent and identically distributed. Conditional on the time elapsed, what is the probability that the determinant of the maze, $M_t$, is non-zero at time $t$? Assume the monkey places zeros as placeholders at entries with $\cdot$ before computing the determinant.

**Attempt**: Numbers are filled in according to a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ - let us denote this counting process by $N(t)$. The probability the determinant is non-zero is roughly the same as the probability we obtain a square matrix and so

$$\underbrace{P(\det M_t\neq 0)\approx P\left(\bigcup_i N(t)=i^2\right)}_{\text{Is this wrong?}}$$

$$=e^{-\lambda t}\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(\lambda t)^{i^2}}{i^2!}=?$$

Hmm - I now realize replacing $\cdot$ entries with zero would most definitely not make the determinant necessarily zero for non-square numbers though still unsure about what the exact probability would be. If $N(t)=3$, then $|M_t|=-3$. If that assumption makes matters too complex, what if we assumed $|M_t|=0$ if there exist any placeholders?

**Question(s)**: Is it reasonable to assume the probability $M_t$ is singular for a perfect square $N(t)$ is small? If so, is there a nice simplification to this sum - the squared terms are throwing me off?